# PostgreSQL bytea to Base64 like SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, binary, base64, bytea

In SQL Server I convert binary to Base64 like this

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5', 'Test') FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
```

and have result "DLxmEfVUC9CAmjiNyVphWw==".

In PostgreSQL i have

```
SELECT encode(md5('Test')::bytea, 'base64')
```

and result is "MGNiYzY2MTFmNTU0MGJkMDgwOWEzODhkYzk1YTYxNWI=".

How can I get result like SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres' `md5()` returns a `text` containing the hexadecimal representation of the hash. By simply casting it to `bytea` you get a `bytea` for that string, not for the value it represents. You can use `decode()` to get the `bytea` value a string represents in hexadecimal notation.

```
SELECT encode(decode(md5('Test'), 'hex'), 'base64');
```